# Как получить последнюю запись в запросе с LIMIT без цикла

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья суть вопроса такая: есть таблица, в которой данные записываются в разбросанном виде.

я хочу получить последнюю 11 строку из таблицы, которую отсортирую по своим параметрам. Как проще всего это сделать? вот сам запрос:

```
$result_count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM core_cards WHERE card_group = '$data_card[card_group]' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 11");
```

Как видно из запроса я хочу обработать именно 11 строку. Могу ли я это сделать в одном запросе без использования цикла??

Comment: `LIMIT 11, 1` ?

Comment: точно! спасибо:)

Answer (score -2):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM core_cards WHERE card_group = '$data_card[card_group]' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
```